# What most current tool for Silverlight UI design?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

It was recently announced that expression studio is being discontinued. What is the most current tool that is being used to develop UI and animations in Silverlight? The "Microsoft Expression Changes" page doesn't make it very clear:
http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/index.html

Thanks!

Edit: Silverlight applications for running in browsers, not windows phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and correct answer is **Blend for Visual Studio 2012 with Update 2**.

The reason for this is: The Expression brand is being discontinued, and for the same reason, Expression Design, Encoder, Web is all being discontinued. The same goes for Expression Blend, however the product Blend is now, and in the future, being branded as **Blend for Visual Studio**, and is now a part of the Visual Studio 2012 suite. 
Since the Expression series is being discontinued, the products is now available for free on the [Expression Website.](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/index.html)

If you have Visual Studio 2012, [install Visual Studio 2012 Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188), and you'll have full support for Silverlight and Sketchflow for Silverlight.

In Blend for Visual Studio you have the ability to import files from programs such as Adobe Photoshop and Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

As the link you shared shows us the blend version for 2012 is still in preview. I haven't heard anything about "expression studio is being discontinued".

Some features for design wasn't included in VS2010 . With VS2012 design feature of Visual Studio improved. But I do not think this will be end of Blend.

As you said blend is not just only UI design tool ,also an animation tool.It looks like Adobe Flash (formerly macromedia's flash). Expression product family is very powerful and I think it must be a big investment. You can open Adobe's Photoshop PSD files with Expression Design. Encoder..SketchFlow for mockup design. many things.

Beside this , I use Blend Preview 5 for SL5 and it's not so different than Blend 4.Even more It gives Blend4 errors on dialogs :)
 So for marketing they won't cancel it.

Comment: Wikipedia lists the development status as "Discontinued", providing citations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Studio

Comment: Yes you are right, I think it is written for Expression Studio 4.